# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Not enough space to create userdata partition

Tags: android-emulator

I have just changed my laptop. On the new laptop, android studio emulator give error when trying to run app: 
**"Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Not enough space to create userdata partition. Available: 6253.683594 MB at C:\Users\RAFIQ.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_27_2.avd, need 7372.800000 MB"**
I have 7 GB space still available in C drive. I have enabled virtualization but still get this error. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

I have found a solution may be helpful to someone :

Just **navigate** to your avd image path in **C:\Users\ashishs\.android\avd\**

and **delete some of the unused images**.

I did the same and the above **issue vanished**

Good Luck :)

Comment: Do you mean the files ending in .img? These don't look like files I should be deleting. Even if they were, I don't imagine them freeing up much memory.

Comment: Actually, that does in fact appear to be the solution. Whether or not deleting the .img files will have any undesirable side effects, I do not know.

Answer (score 5):

1 - Create a directory for your emulators on a larger drive, example: "D:\emulators"

2 - Go to C:\Users<your_user>.android\avd<your_avd_name>

3 - Open the <your_avd_name>.ini file and edit the PATH line

4 - Change "C:\Users<your_user>.android\avd<your_avd_name>" to "D:\emulators<your_avd_name>"

5 - Copy your emulator folder to "D:\emulators"

6 - Run your Emulator

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check your disk space and if you do not have enough space to delete some items, it worked for me.
If this method does not work then go to your advanced setting of AVD Emulator and increase SD card/studio-managed space.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it has nothing to do with RAM of your virtual device. In your case your **C:\Users\RAFIQ** has only **6253.683594** MB of space but minimum required is **7372.800000 MB**, try to free some space there and it will work fine.

Comment: The OP is not referring to C:/Users/RAFIQ. He is referring to C:\Users\RAFIQ.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_27_2.avd, a much more specific folder. What kind of file should he delete in that folder to free up enough MB?

Comment: Looks like deleting the .img files in that folder is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the problem was not the image files but the cache of deleted Virtual Devices. So, I deleted two VDs and I don't see them in the AVD but they were occupying space when I navigated to the avd folder. Deleting them fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

for linux user (ubuntu 20 lts)

- Goto /home//.android/avd/<your_avd_name>
- Delete the .img
  file (for me it was userdata.img and sdcard.img,they are the 2 big
  file for me)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to "avd manager" then "wipe data"

Answer (score 0):

This error message refers to YOUR disk space, not the emulated Android one. It just warns you that there is not enough disk space on your OS to create a virtual partition for Android User data. Empty some space on your system disk (or the one that holds the ADVs) and everything will work as expected.

Answer (score -4):

Goto AVD device manager > Click New Hardware Profile > Change memory RAM: 8000 MB