Android emulatior: not enough space to create userdata partition, suspicious amount of free space requested
It seems like my computer's performance isn't good enough to support default emulators, so I had to do some tricks and I ended up with only working Pixel 7a emulator which had like 600x800 resolution, decreased RAM and stuff. I also stumbled upon other problems while developing my app, so at one point I wiped off the data on it, and from that moment it never launched again, I had just eternal "Starting up" state. I deleted this one and created another one, just the same as the previous, but it also is "Starting up" without actually starting up, and the reason for it is the error "Not enough space to create userdata partition. Available: 31461.046875 MB at C:\Users\anya ananasss.HOME-PC.android\avd..\avd\Pixel_7a_API_34.avd, need 7730941132.799999 MB." Unfortunately, I can't provide 7730 TB of free space :D How can I solve the problem? I also wonder what could've cause it
I've tried to delete .img files, but it didn't work for me.

Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/53931877/3392605

Does this answer your question? Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Not enough space to create userdata partition
